# Select distinct column_a and group by column_b

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that holds these two columns:

```
ip    country
```

These are the viewers I've had on my site. I'm trying to see how many *unique* IPs I get from each country.

I came up with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ip, country, count(*) as views FROM views GROUP BY country
```

I was hoping this would select the number of distinct IPs and the country they are in an group them by country. I would then have a column `views` holding the count.

This isn't working though, this query is returning the total number of row grouped by country. I get the same result with or without the `DISTINCT ip`.

EDIT: I've not expressed myself clearly, what I'm trying to figure out is **how many unique IPs are there from each country**.

Some of my IP's are duplicate in the database, the same IP appears 3-4 times. I want to ignore that:

Input sample:

```
**ip**    **country**
1.1.1.1       USA
1.1.1.1       USA
1.1.1.1       USA
1.1.1.1       USA
1.1.1.2       USA
1.1.1.2       USA
1.1.1.2       USA
1.1.1.3       GER
1.1.1.3       GER
1.1.1.5       GER
```

should output:

```
USA -> 2
GER -> 2
```

ie: there are two different IPs from USA and two different IPs from Germany.

Comment: Can you post a sample of input rows and a sample of what you want the output to look like? It's hard to understand what ip you want returned, in context of the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Are you trying to get the country, the total number of ips, or the total number of _distinct_ ips, then also list those distinct ips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    country,
    count(DISTINCT ip) views
FROM views
GROUP BY country
ORDER BY country;
```

Comment: i believe distinct function always comes first

Comment: @Charlesliam: You are correct, the `DISTINCT` keyword is accepted only in certain locations, e.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT expr)` is valid. But `DISTINCT` is a **keyword**, _not_ a **function**.

Comment: Noted, I'll remember that `Distinct` is a keyword. This will be very helpful on choosing the right answer in OCA multiple choice.

Answer (score 1):

Minor Changes from @Joseph B SQL

```
Select country, views
FROM (SELECT count(DISTINCT ip) views,
             country 
      FROM views
      GROUP BY country
      ORDER BY country);
```

Comment: @Charlesliam: I don't understand what benefit is achieved by using an inline view to obtain the specified resultset. We do know that this results in MySQL materializing the view query into a temporary MyISAM table, before the outer query runs, which can impact performance. Also, this statement will throw the "Every derived table must have an alias" error.